# Portable way of making an ajax request from JS code

Tags: django, jquery

This is probably a silly question, but I can't find an obvious response.

I'm developing a web application using (Geo)Django for the backend and Leaflet, among others, for the frontend. My point is I want to make a url call from my JS code to my Django backend. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<A_URL_HERE>',
    data: {"data":<MY_JSON_DATA>},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("Data saved");

    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Problem saving the data");
    }
});
```

My problem is with the url. I know that [cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html), but for example, if I want to keep different dev/test/prod environments without changing that parameter, how should I do it? In the backend part, I'm following good practices for this kind of problems, but I have short experience with JS and frontend.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use named URL patterns https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Use dynamically generated JavaScript, i.e. the JavaScript file is not a hardcoded static file. Instead it is a template which backend populates with variables (in particular URL);
2. Similar to the one above except that JavaScript is a hardcoded static file and for example you put your URLs in base HTML (which is generated from a template on the server side):

**base.html**

```
<script>window.urls = { "my_url": "{{ my_url }}" };</script>
```

**my_script.js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.urls.my_url,
    ...
});
```

With this you can generate URLs based on you server settings.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted. +1 on your approach; it's similar to mine. I use URI.js to look at the hostname/domain to determine which "base" url my services are running at.